# multiprocessing issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I am just trying to multiprocess and read each line in a text doc. There are 660918 lines, all of which I know to be the same length. Although, with the following code, the length of the lines seem to change, and I cannot figure out why.

```
import multiprocessing

class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self,in_q):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.in_q = in_q
    def run(self):      
        while True:
            try:
                in_q.get()
                temp_line = short_file.readline()
                temp_line = temp_line.strip().split()
                print len(temp_line)
                self.in_q.task_done()
            except:                              
                break     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_proc = 10
    lines = 100000 #660918 is how many lines there actually are
    in_q = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    File = 'HGDP_FinalReport_Forward.txt'
    short_file = open(File)

    for i in range(lines):
        in_q.put(i)    

    for i in range(num_proc):
        worker = Worker(in_q)
        worker.start()
    in_q.join()
```

Comment: Why not read the lines in your main process and farm them out to the child processes with `multiprocessing.Pool`?

Comment: Well the above does not really answer my question, unless for some reason pooling would make all the lines read the same length.

Comment: @user1423020: Surprisingly, it actually would make the lines read the same length.

Comment: @user1423020: This is unrelated to the question, but it is recommended to put as *few* lines as possible in a try clause; this way you can prevent your program from silently ignoring problems in, say, a `print` statement. Furthermore, it is recommended to catch specific exception instead of having a blanket `except` statement that catches anything; this too could hide problems that you did not expect.

Comment: @user1423020: Another important note: I would not recommend using global variables (especially when defined in the main program) in methods. Here, the `short_file` is "silently" used in the `run()` method. This forces users to read *all* your code in order to know what each method uses. The preferred way is to either pass variables explicitly or use (instance or class) attributes.

Comment: @user1423020: Also note that Unix-like platforms use `fork()`, so your child processes know what `short_file` is, but this shouldn't be the case in Windows for example.

Comment: @Amr: +1. But I'm curious, what _does_ happen on Windows? An exception from readline, or does it have separate HANDLEs to the same file so you read it 10 times, or…? (I'd test myself, but I don't have a Windows machine handy…)

Comment: @abarnert: I'm not sure what happens, but on Windows child processes are initiated by importing the parent process file, so anything below `if __name__ == '__main__':` isn't processed, so I think using `short_file` would raise a `NameError` exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're opening a file in the main process, then reading from that file in the child processes. You can't do that.

Deep under the covers, the file object is effectively a raw file handle and a memory buffer. Each process shares the file handle, but each one has its own memory buffer.

Let's say all of the lines are 50 bytes each, and the memory buffer is 4096 bytes.

Process 1 calls readline, which reads bytes 0-4095 from the file into its buffer, then scans that buffer for a newline, which is 50 bytes in, and it returns the first 50 bytes. So far, so good.

Process 2 calls readline, which reads bytes 4096-8191 from the file into its buffer, then scans that buffer for a newline. The first one is at 4100, which is 5 bytes in, so it returns the first 5 bytes.

And so on.

You could theoretically get around this by doing unbuffered I/O, but really, why? Why not just read the lines in your main process? Besides avoiding this problem, that would also probably improve parallelism—the I/O is inherently sequential, so all of those processes will spend most of their time blocked on I/O, which means they're not doing you any good.

As a side note, near the top of the loop in run, you're doing in_q.get() instead of self.in_q.get(). (That happens to work because in_q is a global variable that never goes away and self.in_q is just a copy of it, but you don't want to rely on that.)

Comment: Wow, excellent answer.  I wish I could upvote more than once.

Comment: This helps, but I am a bit confused on how to organize the code such that I am reading lines in main instead of in the children.

Answer (score 1):

So, I changed it to use Pool, and it seems to work. Is the following better?

```
import multiprocessing as mp

File = 'HGDP_FinalReport_Forward.txt'
#short_file = open(File)
test = []

def pro(temp_line):
    temp_line = temp_line.strip().split()
    return len(temp_line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("HGDP_FinalReport_Forward.txt") as lines:
        pool = mp.Pool(processes = 10)
        t = pool.map(pro,lines.readlines())
    print t
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't have added this as an answer, but… I'm not sure exactly how you _should_ have added it. Anyway, yes, I'd say it's better. First, because you're doing all the file reading in the parent process, it now works. It also means you're distributing the CPU-bound work instead of the I/O-bound work, and there's nothing blocking in the distributed work, which both mean more efficiency and parallelism. And using makes it shorter, easier to read, and harder to make trivial mistakes in (like the in_q instead of self.in_q).